# htaccess RewriteRule force to put s in the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^member  member.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule member/(.*)/(.*)$ member.html?a=$1&b=$2
```

so the should be like https://example.com/member/query_1/query_2

the problem is this link wont work unless I add (s) character to the end of member word in the url

so the working link is https://example.com/members/query_1/query_2

unless it return me 404 error
its work fine in the xamp localhost but when I upload to server I have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^member/?$ member.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule member/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ member.html?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

`Options -MultiViews` will turn content negotiation service off.  Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.